# User type according different registration form with differnrt payment in joomla

Tags: joomla2.5, membership, usertype

i have two user type "Retailer" and "Private" but i want to open different registration form for both user type and also different payment method so how i do it means which component i use for that or any plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtuemart has the ability to have different user types with different pricing options.

If you wanted different user types to also have different payment types, then you would need to add some custom code to the payment portion of the checkout to only display the types available to the current user's group.